# trouble in create custom table for custom model

Tags: database, model, resource-model

I get some trouble in auto create table for model . I create module 'rewardpoint' by moduleCreator and it generate rewardpoint model automatically,But i want to create new Model 'rate' in my module . So , this is my code :

-config.xml

```
<models>
        <rate>
            <class>Magestore_Rewardpoint_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>rate_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </rate>
        <rate_mysql4>
            <class>Magestore_Rewardpoint_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <rate>
                    <table>rewardpoints_rate</table>
                </rate>
            </entities>
        </rate_mysql4>
    </models>
<resources>
        <rewardpoint_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Magestore_Rewardpoint</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </rewardpoint_setup>
        <rewardpoint_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </rewardpoint_write>
        <rewardpoint_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </rewardpoint_read>
   </resources>
```

And in sql folder , i change code too

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * create rewardpoint table
 */
$installer->run("

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('rewardpoints_rate')};

CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('rewardpoints_rate')} (
  `rate_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `direction` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `point` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_group` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rate_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

");
```

Then i refesh browser and see my phpadmin result , there's no table name 'rewardpoints_rate'.

Comment: Please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to learn how to debug. I would think you have a caching problem. And if this is your complete config.xml you might have missed the point with XML?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add this as a comment, but then it is unreadable.

You don't need all the XML nodes, because magento adds them automatically:

```
<resources>
    <rewardpoint_setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </rewardpoint_setup>
    <rewardpoint_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </rewardpoint_write>
    <rewardpoint_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </rewardpoint_read>
```

You can remove them if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For run sql_setup you need define resource

```
<resources>
    <rate_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Magestore_Rewardpoint</module>
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
    </rate_setup>
    <rate_read>
    <connection>
        <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
    </rate_read>
    <rate_write>
    <connection>
        <use>core_write</use>
    </connection>
    </rate_write>
</resources>
```

Comment: i fixed it , its because this module has run before . so i have to delete its cache from core_resource . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Also try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Magestore_Rewardpoint>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Magestore_Rewardpoint>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <rewardpoint>
         <class>Magestore_Rewardpoint_Helper</class>
      </rewardpoint>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
      <rewardpoint_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Magestore_Rewardpoint</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </rewardpoint_setup>
      <rewardpoint_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </rewardpoint_write>
      <rewardpoint_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </rewardpoint_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Also try this code for app\code\local\Magestore\Rewardpoint\sql\rewardpoint_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table rewardpoints_rate('rate_id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 'direction' smallint(6) NOT NULL,'point` int(11) NOT NULL,'money' int(11) NOT NULL, 'customer_group' varchar(20) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ('rate_id'));
SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: i fixed it , its because this module has run before . so i have to delete its cache from core_resource . thank you